# Can't post string to Rest API from Android [Java]

Tags: java, c#, android, rest, post

I am programming simple app for android and i need to post data to my server. I always receive Http code 200 (success) but server data never receive.

The server is running ASP.NET MVC 5 project. Here is source code of page which i am calling from android.:

```
public string Post([FromBody]string data) // webapi 2.0
    {
        if (data == null) return "error. you must send data";

        // my logic..

        return "OK";
    }
```

I always receive "error. you must send data" :(

Here is source code of client side (Android app)

```
public static int RegisterNewUser(String nick, String pwd) {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try{
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://helpforimigrants.somee.com/api/User");

        StringEntity params = new StringEntity("simple string. just plain text, simple sentence");

        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    } catch(Exception e){

    } finally {
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

please help, i am programming beginner.

Comment: First thought, try changing your content-type header in the Android code to "application/text".

Comment: @Kevin `application/text` is not a standard media type. You should use `text/plain` or any other standard media type, see  http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#text for reference.

Comment: @francescoforesti you are absolutely right, text/plain, although not what I typed, is exactly what I meant. Thank you.

Comment: When i use `text/plain` i receive error code 415